# validate without having to use submit button using parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I want to use all the built in feature of parsley.js which is just specifying "required" in the tag like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlmyid" runat="server" required>
```

The validation occurs after you would normally click on submit button and it validates.  There is a popup message at the error which I like.

On my form I have a button that calls a server side function:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSaveUpdate" runat="server" Text='Save' CommandName="SaveUp"
                            OnClick="SaveUpdate" Style="float: right;" />
```

1. What is the best way to validate the form then call a server side function to process everything into the database
2. How can I integrate the normal form checking with this server side function call, instead of having to use the "submit" button?  I want it to validate the entire form when I click on the button that calls the server function.
3. I don't want to have to specify another type of error message and just use the default that came with Parsley.  A few examples I have seen having to specify the message all over again with a div.

Can I have a dummy submit button and call the onclick event, before calling my server side button event?  Not sure how to do that...

thanks

**Partial Solution to What I am looking for:**

I am trying to implement this in a SharePoint webpart which poses additional challenges.
1. Registering the form with Parsley - Since it's in a SP web part which has a master page template, any local form tag gets removed since there is a master form tag called "aspnetForm".  However, registering the form "aspnetForm" didn't seem to work too well.
   I even tried to specify clientmodeid="static" so the form does get removed and then register the local form id, but Parsley can't seem to find this either.
   Lastly, I found this site: http://vogtland.ws/markedwardvogt/?p=1142 which shows it register it with "form".  Not sure why that works, but it does.

2. Then I use this very basic validation for parsley and change the function a little bit from the site mentioned above.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function customValidation() {


   $('form').parsley();


   if (!($('form').parsley().validate())) {

       alert("form is not valid2");

   }
   else {
       alert("form is valid2");
   }

   }
   </script>
   ```
3. The validation give an error message underneath the fields.  ***But I want to use the nicer built in pop up message...does anyone know how I can do that?***

Comment: I think the pop up error message is built from the base jquery library and not from parsley.  It seems like once you do any type of customization, you are stuck with the default error message underneath or display it else where in the div section.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used parsley.js - but they have to offer a way to perform validation manually (not from clicking submit).  OnClientClick attribute can be used to call a function in javascript before callin ganything in the server;

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSaveUpdate" runat="server" Text='Save' CommandName="SaveUp" 
         OnClientClick="validateForm();" OnClick="SaveUpdate" Style="float: right;" />
```

then something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(){
  // parsley.js has this function from their docs
  // it prevents submission if not valid
  validate(group, force)

}

</script>
```